# Changing working folder location

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to change the location of working folder. How to make the changes in my SVN repository? I am using TortoiseSVN client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to move your entire working copy, just move it in the file system.

If you want to move a folder within the working copy and later commit the move, right click on the folder, pick TortoiseSVN->Rename.

Change `YourFolder` to something like `..\..\NewFolder\AnotherFolder\YourFolder`. Note that `..\..\NewFolder\AnotherFolder\` must exist before the operation.

Another way to move files and folders from TortoiseSVN is to use the Repository browser. There you can easily drag'n drop them to new locations. The files are moved in the remote svn repository. You need to update your working copy to get the movements locally.

Comment: TortoiseSVN also allows move using right-click drag & drop within a working copy.

Comment: I ran into a problem with this. I had my project in my local IIS. IIS went corrupt on me so I needed to move the project out so I could use the default web server in Visual Studio. Now, SVN shows changes in both my new location, and the uncommitted changes I had in IIS. I have changed all references to local host I can find in the project and they wont go away.

Answer (score 2):

You can just copy your working folder outside of Tortoise-svn (with standard copy operation). After that Tortoise will work with your new location.

Answer (score 1):

You can really clean up a lot in your working copy by using the right drag functionality in your explorer. Check the link below for some features you most likely never knew about:

http://tortoisesvn.net/mostforgottenfeature.html