# How to relocate local svn folder in tortoise SVN(windows)?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

On Windows, I want to relocate my local SVN checkout folder.

Currently I am using TortoiseSVN and I want to move the folder to the `www\` folder so that I can run it on my local `wamp` server.

How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "move my folder to the www folder so that I can

run it on my local"?

Comment: i haved edited the question.

Comment: Why don't you do fresh `svn checkout` to the www directory?

Comment: Because I dont checkout will require 2 GB download.

Answer (score 7):

Copy-paste the entire folder to different location. As long as it contains `.svn` directory and TortoiseSVN is installed on the machine, it shold work.

Comment: Yep. See this related question: [Changing working folder location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005275/)